# How to run git diff in github actions

Tags: git, github-actions

I am getting this:

```
Command failed: git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

I want to run `git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD` in my branch to get a list of the files that were changed. It's working locally but not on GitHub actions. What must I do?

My code is this:

```
name: build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  run:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Configure Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Publish file changes to Slack
        # HERE I run `git diff` in node.js process
        run: "SLACK_TOKEN=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} npx ts-node scripts/publishSlackUpdate"
      - name: Build TOC
        run: make toc
      - name: Commit build changes
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
        with:
          author_name: Docs Builder
          author_email: docs@mysite.com
          message: 'Updated build'
          add: '*.md'
```

Comment: Did you check out your repository in your action? It would be easier to help you if you were to show us the failing workflow.

Comment: I can't show the failing workflow it's a private repo. No I didn't check it out, how do I do that? It's on a specific branch, the current PR branch. Updated with my configuration.

Comment: By "the failing workflow", I meant the workflow definition,  which you have posted. Thanks! It looks like you did check out the repository (via the `actions/checkout@v2` action). Let me see if I can reproduce the failure....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for the [actions/checkout@v2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout) action, you'll see it performs a shallow clone with a single revision by default:

```
    # Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
    # Default: 1
    fetch-depth: ''
```

Because it only fetches a single revision, there is no `HEAD^`.

You can fix this by setting the `fetch-depth` option on the checkout action. Setting it to `0` will fetch the entire history; alternatively, for what you're doing you could probably just set it to `2`:

```
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
```

Comment: how do you fetch the entire github repo? I want to do something else where I inspect the entire commit history.

Comment: That would be "Setting it to 0 will fetch the entire history"

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. There's also an issue where they say that it isn't possible https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/161 ‍♂️

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl it seems to work just fine. I tried it on [on one of my repositories](https://github.com/larsks/symtool/runs/1847406380?check_suite_focus=true) and the `actions/checkout@v2` action checked out the entire repository history.

Comment: @larsks I don't see where you run git diff in either of your two workflows,  test-and-publish.yml  or  test-only.yml

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl The current actions don't, but if you follow the link I posted, you can see the commands that were run and the output they generated. E.g. expand "Run actions/checkout@v2", then expand the inset "Run actions/checkout@v2" to see the parameters. Expand "Run git log" to see the command and output showing a full git log, rather than the log from a shallow repository.

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl I made you a complete example [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-hrdwdmrbl) (I grabbed the GNU hello repository and added an example workflow).

Comment: @larsks Okay I replicated the problem I was having with your code. IF you specify a specific fetch-depth then it doesn't work. [check it out](https://github.com/hrdwdmrbl/so-example-hrdwdmrbl/pull/1/checks?check_run_id=1858485983)

Answer (score 15):

Putting `origin/` before branch name worked for me

```
git diff --name-only origin/main origin/${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}
```

Comment: The same case with me also. Not sure why they have made it mandatory.

Comment: To elaborate, I needed to git diff against 'main', for which I needed to still set the `fetch-depth: 0` on checkout. Additionally I needed to set my diff against `origin/main`. I'm assuming that having all the history, does not also include the branch refs?

Comment: In one setup this worked for me. Then in another setup it didnt work and I had to remove `origin/` from the feature branch. Really bizarre why there isnt consistency either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jitterbit/get-changed-files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-all-changed-files) GA Action:

```
- id: files
  uses: jitterbit/get-changed-files@v1
- run: |
    for changed_file in ${{ steps.files.outputs.all }}; do
      echo "Do something with this ${changed_file}."
    done
```

Comment: I found another action that's not abandoned and does the same: [tjactions/changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files)